# Divide a data set into bins of size n matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a data set of size 11490x1. the data is recorded every 0.25 second(i.e. 4hz). So, 1 second accounts for 4 data points. The goal here is to further create sub sets every 3 seconds, meaning that I want to look at data every 3 seconds and analyze it. for example: if I had data such as [1 2 3 4 5 6 8 2 4 2 4 3 2 4 2 5 2 5 24 2 5 1 5 1], I want to have a sub set [1 2 3 4 5 6 8 2 4 2 4 3 ] and so on...

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `reshape` command which will allow you to reshape your vector into a matrix (remember to pad your vector with zeros or truncate to make sure the matrix will fit).

Comment: I tried reshape, it gives an error saying that the data shouldn't have decimals in it, the data I am using has points like 0.2, 0.1 etc etc

Comment: reshape does decimals, maybe you did not pad your vector? Look at Dan's answer, he has it covered :D

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't pad the vector. I am not sure what it means though

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you plan to "analyse" your data. The simplest way is to use a loop:

```
n = 4*3;
breaks = 0:n:numel(data)
for i = 1:numel(breaks)-1
    sub = data(breaks(i)+1:breaks(i+1));
    %// do analysis
    %// OR sub{i} = data(breaks(i)+1:breaks(i+1));
end
```

A vectorized approach might use `reshape(data,[],12)` after padding `data` so that `mod(numel(data),12)==0`

A third way might be to break your matrix up into a cell array using [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) or in a for loop like above but instead of `sub=...` rather use `sub{i}=...`

Comment: Is there a reason the output sub is size 1x13 ? When i tried to use an index for sub it runs in an error. I used sub(1,i) in the for loop

Comment: The edited version is giving the right index, Now, the code is overwriting each value of sub, how do I save the output 'sub' each time?

Comment: As mentioned, either use `sub{i}=...` or use `reshape` instead of the loop. Note I edited the loop again so that you can call `sub{i}=...` instead of `sub{i-1}=...`

Comment: I tried what you said already and it gives the following error: "Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object." I used data = rand(1,11490)